# Error in ANOVA when $n$ differs between groups

Tags: r, anova, error-message

```
> July=c(1.28,1.35,1.19,1.43)
> October=c(1.83,1.62,1.78,1.49,1.55)
> January=c(1.72,1.91,1.68,1.83,1.79)
> April=c(1.32,1.40,1.22,1.28)
> my.squirrel.dat=data.frame(April,July,October,January)

Error in data.frame(April, July, October, January) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 4, 5
```

To compare these 4 sets, is it possible to use an ANOVA?

Comment: If you have different n's for the different months, you could add an `NA` to the end pf the months with 4 so R won't complain.

Comment: This question essentially asks whether it is possible to perform an ANOVA when the n's are different, which I think makes it on-topic here

Comment: ANOVA is perfectly valid on different $n$; your problem is that data frames aren't designed for ragged arrays; they need columns of the same length. The way to put different length columns together is either: (i) use a list of vectors; (ii) fill to constant length with NA values; or (iii) stack all the data into a single column and use a second as a group indicator (a *factor* in R). Of the three, the last is probably the most idiomatic.

Comment: @Glen_b A quite different problem with this example is that there is structure in the four seasons that isn't captured at all by ANOVA. That is, the four seasons could be shuffled into different order and the ANOVA results would remain identical. Even with just the coarseness of four seasons, an appropriate model is probably a sinusoid in time of year.  Furthermore, inspecting the data suggests a winter maximum and a summer minimum. This should not be surprising biologically or environmentally!

Comment: @Nick - absolutely - the specific data have issues that would suggest ANOVA is an unsuitable analysis; I didn't address that in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you would do this with R. Notice how I arrange your data in "long format", i.e., in a value column and a column for the categories.

```
DF <- rbind(data.frame(value = July, month = "July"),
            data.frame(value = October, month = "October"),
            data.frame(value = January, month = "January"),
            data.frame(value = April, month = "April"))

summary(aov(value ~ month, data = DF))
#            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
#month        3 0.7953 0.26512   22.22 1.37e-05 ***
#Residuals   14 0.1670 0.01193                     
#---
#  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

**Edit:**

@Nick Cox correctly points out, that this approach neglects some important aspects of your data.

First you should plot it:

```
DF$month <- factor(DF$month, 
                   levels = month.name,
                   ordered = TRUE)

plot(value ~ month, data = DF)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Apparently, there is some seasonality in your values. A very rough approach would be to handle the months as an ordered factor:

```
summary(lm(value ~ month, data = DF))
#Call:
#lm(formula = value ~ month, data = DF)
#
#Residuals:
#     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#-0.16400 -0.08025 -0.01050  0.08225  0.17600 
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)  1.51438    0.02590  58.460  < 2e-16 ***
#month.L     -0.08687    0.04945  -1.757    0.101    
#month.Q      0.41125    0.05181   7.938  1.5e-06 ***
#month.C     -0.03455    0.05406  -0.639    0.533    
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#Residual standard error: 0.1092 on 14 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:  0.8265,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.7893 
#F-statistic: 22.22 on 3 and 14 DF,  p-value: 1.372e-05
```

The strongly significant positive quadratic coefficient confirms the seasonality with lowest values in summer and highest in fall/winter.

If you are feeling adventurous you could model this with a cosinor model:

```
library(cosinor)

DF$numtime <- as.numeric(DF$month)
summary(fit <- cosinor.lm(value ~ time(numtime), period = 12, data = DF))
#Raw model coefficients:
#            estimate standard.error lower.CI upper.CI p.value
#(Intercept)   1.5144         0.0266   1.4622   1.5665  0.0000
#rrr           0.2937         0.0376   0.2200   0.3674  0.0000
#sss          -0.0275         0.0374  -0.1007   0.0458  0.4629
#
#***********************
#
#Transformed coefficients:
#            estimate standard.error lower.CI upper.CI p.value
#(Intercept)   1.5144         0.0266   1.4622   1.5665  0.0000
#amp           0.2950         0.0376   0.2213   0.3687  0.0000
#acr          -0.0932         0.1267  -0.3416   0.1552  0.462

library(ggplot2)
ggplot.cosinor.lm(fit) +
  geom_point(data = DF, aes(x = numtime, y = value), size = 3)
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Please see also my comment above on the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

An ANOVA compares the variances within each group (here, within each month) to the variances across groups. You just need more than one data point in each group (and more than one group) to estimate these comparisons. Beyond that, the $n$s don't have to be equal, though your test will be more powerful if the groups are nearly the same size.

The problem here is actually how you're assembling the data frame. Imagine that the frame is a table. Each argument to `data.frame` adds a row to the table. Your command creates a data frame that looks like

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c} 
 & \text{July} & \text{October} & \text{January} &\text{April}\\ \hline
\text{ 1} & 1.28 & 1.83 & 1.72  & 1.32  \\ \hline
\text{ 2} & 1.35 & 1.62 & 1.91  & 1.40\\ \hline
\text{ 3} & 1.19 & 1.78 & 1.68  & 1.22\\ \hline
\text{ 4} & 1.43 & 1.49 & 1.83  & 1.28\\ \hline
\text{ 5} &      & 1.55 \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

You might organize the data like this in a spreadsheet, but it is the wrong format for R. Each argument to data.frame needs to be the same length, so you would need to pad the shorter vectors out with `NA`s. However, that's still not quite right, since you typically want to arrange the data in "long" form, like this
$$ \begin{array}{c|c|c} 
         & \text{Month} & \text{Outcome} \\ \hline 
\text{1} & \text{July} & 1.28 \\ \hline
\text{2} & \text{July} & 1.35 \\ \hline
\text{3} & \text{July} & 1.19 \\ \hline
\cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\ \hline
\text{17} & \text{April} &1.28 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

This arranges the data in a way that matches the structure of your question ("Does the outcome vary with month?"): you have one dependent variable (the outcome) and one factor (the month).  To build this, you call `data.frame(month, outcome)`, where `outcome[i]` contains the outcome for the month in `month[i]`.

Now, you can easily describe the relationship between these variables for (e.g.) `aov` by doing something like `aov(outcome ~ month, data=mydataframe)`.

If you have more questions on the ANOVA itself, feel free to ask here. You'll have better luck with R syntax questions on stackoverflow, where they're more on topic.

Comment: Please see also my comment on the question.